# Groovy in Jasperreports NoClassDefFound Error

Tags: groovy, jasper-reports, noclassdeffounderror, jaspersoft-studio

[Official example](http://community.jaspersoft.com/blog/scriptlet-example-jaspersoft-6x-begineers-hello-world-sample-example) does not work with "groovy" set as language.

I cannot figure out why. I need to use "groovy" because of lots of old reports!

*My steps that lead to error:*

1. Setup example as per link above (use eclipse to create simple java script and export as jar then import into jaspersoft studio)
2. Create "Scriptlet" in Jaspersoft Studio like so:[image]
3. Run report (Works just like the example!) [image]
4. Set the language of the report to "groovy" -> Crash [image]

After I have completed the example I switch the language to groovy and I do get the error below and cannot figure out how to solve it (works with language: java).

*Error:*

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when 

compiling report expressions class file: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during class generation: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class hello.Test4 due to missing dependency net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRScriptletException

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class hello.Test4 due to missing dependency net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRScriptletException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.convertUncaughtExceptionToCompilationError(CompilationUnit.java:1091)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1069)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:591)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRGroovyCompiler.compileUnits(JRGroovyCompiler.java:102)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:203)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportCompiler.compileReport(JasperReportCompiler.java:294)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.compileJasperDesign(ReportControler.java:465)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.access$15(ReportControler.java:442)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler$5.run(ReportControler.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class hello.Test4 due to missing dependency net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRScriptletException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureClassNode(Java5.java:391)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.lazyClassInit(ClassNode.java:265)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getUnresolvedSuperClass(ClassNode.java:1004)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getUnresolvedSuperClass(ClassNode.java:999)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getSuperClass(ClassNode.java:993)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.isDerivedFrom(ClassNode.java:936)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.castToNonPrimitiveIfNecessary(InvocationWriter.java:858)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OperandStack.doConvertAndCast(OperandStack.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OperandStack.doGroovyCast(OperandStack.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitCastExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:741)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.CastExpression.visit(CastExpression.java:87)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.prepareSiteAndReceiver(CallSiteWriter.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.prepareSiteAndReceiver(CallSiteWriter.java:224)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.makeCallSite(CallSiteWriter.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCachedCall(InvocationWriter.java:307)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:392)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeInvokeMethodCall(InvocationWriter.java:88)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeInvokeMethod(InvocationWriter.java:459)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethodCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:767)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.BinaryExpressionHelper.evaluateEqual(BinaryExpressionHelper.java:316)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.BinaryExpressionHelper.eval(BinaryExpressionHelper.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitBinaryExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:638)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.BinaryExpression.visit(BinaryExpression.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeExpressionStatement(StatementWriter.java:607)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeExpressionStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:357)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitExpressionStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:620)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(StatementWriter.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:158)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitBlockStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:288)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(StatementWriter.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:158)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitBlockStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitStdMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitConstructorOrMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:387)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:507)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1086)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitClass(AsmClassGenerator.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$16.call(CompilationUnit.java:813)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1055)
    ... 10 more

1 error
.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRGroovyCompiler.compileUnits(JRGroovyCompiler.java:106)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:203)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportCompiler.compileReport(JasperReportCompiler.java:294)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.compileJasperDesign(ReportControler.java:465)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.access$15(ReportControler.java:442)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler$5.run(ReportControler.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during class generation: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class hello.Test4 due to missing dependency net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRScriptletException

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class hello.Test4 due to missing dependency net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRScriptletException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.convertUncaughtExceptionToCompilationError(CompilationUnit.java:1091)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1069)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:591)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRGroovyCompiler.compileUnits(JRGroovyCompiler.java:102)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:203)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.eclipse.builder.JasperReportCompiler.compileReport(JasperReportCompiler.java:294)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.compileJasperDesign(ReportControler.java:465)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.access$15(ReportControler.java:442)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler$5.run(ReportControler.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class hello.Test4 due to missing dependency net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRScriptletException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureClassNode(Java5.java:391)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.lazyClassInit(ClassNode.java:265)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getUnresolvedSuperClass(ClassNode.java:1004)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getUnresolvedSuperClass(ClassNode.java:999)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getSuperClass(ClassNode.java:993)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.isDerivedFrom(ClassNode.java:936)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.castToNonPrimitiveIfNecessary(InvocationWriter.java:858)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OperandStack.doConvertAndCast(OperandStack.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OperandStack.doGroovyCast(OperandStack.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitCastExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:741)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.CastExpression.visit(CastExpression.java:87)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.prepareSiteAndReceiver(CallSiteWriter.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.prepareSiteAndReceiver(CallSiteWriter.java:224)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.makeCallSite(CallSiteWriter.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCachedCall(InvocationWriter.java:307)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:392)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeInvokeMethodCall(InvocationWriter.java:88)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeInvokeMethod(InvocationWriter.java:459)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethodCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:767)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.BinaryExpressionHelper.evaluateEqual(BinaryExpressionHelper.java:316)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.BinaryExpressionHelper.eval(BinaryExpressionHelper.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitBinaryExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:638)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.BinaryExpression.visit(BinaryExpression.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeExpressionStatement(StatementWriter.java:607)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeExpressionStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:357)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitExpressionStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:620)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(StatementWriter.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:158)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitBlockStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:288)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeIfElse(StatementWriter.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeIfElse(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitIfElse(AsmClassGenerator.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.IfStatement.visit(IfStatement.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(StatementWriter.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:158)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitBlockStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitStdMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitConstructorOrMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:387)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:507)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1086)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitClass(AsmClassGenerator.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$16.call(CompilationUnit.java:813)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1055)
    ... 10 more

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1075)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:591)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRGroovyCompiler.compileUnits(JRGroovyCompiler.java:102)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: I can not reproduce this in JasperSoft Studio 6.2.1 compiling the jar with java 6, you need add more information on version of java you compile with, version of jasper-reports, version of JasperSoft Studio, version of groovy-all jar

Comment: Find the jar with class `net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRScriptletException` and add it to the classpath. Or it is already there and still seeing this error?

Comment: Jasper studio 6.3.1 - someone sais here that this is a bug: http://community.jaspersoft.com/jaspersoft-studio/issues/9476#comment-840956

Answer (score 0):

I'm using japser with java not groovy, all I need to do is just remove the language="groovy" from the jasper xml file and compile the report normally, the default compiler should be java if the class path of the iReport set correctly to the java SDK.